# Must an exterior angle of a polygon be less than 180 degrees?

Tags: geometry, angle, polygons

Is it true that all exterior angles of any polygon, be it convex, concave, or complex, must be less than 180 degrees? I believe this to be true and cannot think of any counterexample. Am I correct? If so, is there a simple proof or even an intuitive explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Exterior Angle is the angle between any side of a shape, and a line extended from the next side. So the interior and exterior angle will add to 180 degrees. For the exterior angle to be 180 degrees, the interior angle must be 0 degrees. So yes, the exterior angle will always be less than 180 degrees.